# PDF direct printing using adobe reader

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I tried this code for PDF printing but when **Adobe Reader** open this gives an error that

> file and directory could not found

The code runs fine and opens Adobe but does not load the file for printing. Instead it shows an error dialog. Can anybody tell me where I am wrong?

```
private void PrintFormPdfData(byte[] formPdfData)
    {`enter code here`
        string tempFile;

        tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();



        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(formPdfData, 0, formPdfData.Length);
            fs.Flush();
        }

        try
        {
            string gsArguments;
            string gsLocation;
            ProcessStartInfo gsProcessInfo;
            Process gsProcess;

            gsArguments = string.Format("-grey -noquery -printer \"HP LaserJet 5M\" \"{0}\"", tempFile);
            gsLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsprint.exe";

            gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            gsProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            gsProcessInfo.FileName = gsLocation;
            gsProcessInfo.Arguments = gsArguments;

            gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
            gsProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
        finally
        {
            File.Delete(tempFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not see any reference to acrobat reader in your code...

Comment: Do you have gsprint installed?

Answer (score -1):

fs.Close() is missing. So the file cannot be opened by gsprint.

*Note: Flush before Close is useless.*

Comment: Close is performed when the FileStream is disposed.

Comment: Your remark is correct but nothing guarantees that the procedure ends before the gsprint process starts.

Comment: gsProcess.WaitForExit ensures that that child process (gsprint) is done before returning.  Therefore the file is closed when gsprint is invoked and deleted after it has returned.

Comment: @bubbafa: _Agreed_ Except if gsprint execute another process.

Comment: That's a good point.  

I admit, I only have used gsprint a few times in scenarios like this but I've never run into a problem where it returned before printing as done (or rather fully queued).  

I looked at the gsprint source and don't see a path where it would return before the child process is complete (it redirects stdin/stdout of the child to a pipe it reads/writes to/from - and it stays around until the child is done) - but I do agree that this is possible issue.